# Alternative to CTE'S to reduce verbosity in SQL query

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I have a transactional table that looks like this:

```
timestamp           | cashier   | amount |
-----------------------------------------
2023-05-01 07:15:25 | cashier_1 | 25     |
2023-05-01 08:16:25 | cashier_1 | 18     |
2023-05-01 09:35:00 | cashier_2 | 76     |
2023-05-01 10:26:00 | cashier_3 | 45     |
2023-05-01 10:42:13 | cashier_3 | 12     |
2023-05-01 11:04:12 | cashier_4 | 80     |
```

With this table, I'm making a report that shows the number of transactions for each cashier by the hour:

```
hour  | cashier_1 | cashier_2 | cashier_3 |
-------------------------------------------
7:00  |   43      |   14      |    98     | 
8:00  |   12      |   67      |    76     |
9:00. |   15      |   32      |    54     |
10:00 |   54      |   45      |    34     |
11:00 |   12      |   98      |    54     |
12:00 |   18      |   76      |    65     |
13:00 |   56      |   12      |    76     |
```

The query I'm using to build this report is composed of several CTE's:

```
WITH cashier_1 AS (
    SELECT HOUR(timestamp) AS HOUR,
        COUNT(*) as cashier
    FROM my_table
    WHERE cashier = 'cashier_1'
    GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp)
    ORDER BY HOUR(timestamp)
),
cashier_2 AS (
    SELECT HOUR(timestamp) AS HOUR,
        COUNT(*) as cashier
    FROM my_table
    WHERE cashier = 'cashier_2'
    GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp)
    ORDER BY HOUR(timestamp)
),
cashier_3 AS (
    SELECT HOUR(timestamp) AS HOUR,
        COUNT(*) as cashier
    FROM my_table
    WHERE cashier = 'cashier_3'
    GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp)
    ORDER BY HOUR(timestamp)
)
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(c1.HOUR AS varchar), ':00') as HOUR,
    c1.cashier AS cashier_1,
    c2.cashier AS cashier_2,
    c3.cashier AS cashier_3
FROM cashier_1 c1
    LEFT JOIN cashier_2 c2 ON c1.HOUR = c2.HOUR
    LEFT JOIN cashier_3 c3 ON c1.HOUR = c3.HOUR
ORDER BY c1.HOUR
```

However, there are a lot of cashiers and in this way, I will end up with a query of hundreds of lines.

My question is ¿ Is there any SQL approach to reduce the verbosity of the query and hence improve the maintainability and extensibility of the code?

Comment: Are your cashier "ID"s literally like this (cashier_1, cashier_2, etc.) - or are you just using that as an example?  That is - are the column headings really likely to be something like a cashier's actual name, or their employee number, etc.?

Comment: Also - you say you are making a "report" ... what are you using specifically to generate the output?  Depending on what tool / application is being used to present the end-result to users, you may not necessarily need to have the SQL query looking exactly like the final result ..... your report app could do the pivoting/column layouts for you.  Or, even if the data gets dropped out to Excel, then a Pivot Table could produce the final visual result.  (You could potentially also have an Excel spreadsheet that's directly connected to the database, for "live" data updates)

Comment: I'd turn the result around - one column per hour, and one row per cashier. (I.e. never more than 24 columns, even with a huge number of cashiers.)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a calendar/hour table here, along with conditional aggregation.

```sql
WITH hours AS (
    SELECT 1 AS hour UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4  UNION ALL SELECT 5  UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7  UNION ALL SELECT 8  UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL
    SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12 UNION ALL
    SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15 UNION ALL
    SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 17 UNION ALL SELECT 18 UNION ALL
    SELECT 19 UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL SELECT 21 UNION ALL
    SELECT 22 UNION ALL SELECT 23
)

SELECT
    h.hour,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN cashier = 'cashier_1' THEN 1 END) AS cashier_1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN cashier = 'cashier_2' THEN 1 END) AS cashier_2,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN cashier = 'cashier_3' THEN 1 END) AS cashier_3
FROM hours h
LEFT JOIN my_table m
    ON HOUR(m.timestamp) = h.hour
GROUP BY h.hour
ORDER BY h.hour;
```

Comment: I think the OP is more concerned about not having to go back to the query every time a new cashier comes along ....

Comment: @Craig Then the OP would need Dynamic SQL, and that's very complex.